Concurrent Request to Single Prometheus Server
I have 2 software components A and B which send their time series metrics to the same prometheus database.
I want to have 2 clients A and B which will talk to the same prometheus server for request software components A and B's data concurrently.
Basically i want to have 2 clients A and B which want to talk to same prometheus server concurrently for fetching metrics.
Is it possible?
I tried to look for the answer in prometheus documentation for this but couldn't find any answers.

Prometheus implements REST approach in the server, so it has no problems with concurrent requests. Can't even imagine why you think it might have problems with this.
